# Where to find the path for my relay chain when starting a parachain?

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator, relay-chain, chainspec, substrate-parachain-template

I'm trying to use this code to start a parachain (from [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/connect-a-local-parachain/)):

```
./target/release/parachain-collator \
--alice \
--collator \
--force-authoring \
--chain rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json \
--base-path /tmp/parachain/alice \
--port 40333 \
--ws-port 8844 \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain <relay chain raw chain spec> \
--port 30343 \
--ws-port 9977
```

However, I'm not sure what I should specify for the `relay chain raw chain spec`. I know where my parachain spec is (`rococo-local-parachain-2000-raw.json`), but for the relay chain I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [previous section](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/local-relay/).

The tutorial is using this [spec](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/blob/main/static/assets/tutorials/cumulus/chain-specs/rococo-custom-2-raw.json). You could download this directly.

Or, build it yourself:

1. `git clone https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot.git && cd polkadot`
2. `cargo build --release --features rococo-native`
3. `target/release/polkadot build-spec --chain rococo-local --disable-default-bootnode --raw > relaychain.json`